# How to use a non-sliver widget in a CustomScrollView

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to add a Text widget into CustomScrollView but I got issues like the target is not the same.

This is my widget:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final double statusBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
  return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      body: CustomScrollView(
        semanticChildCount: 2,
        slivers: <Widget>[
          _buildAppBar(context, statusBarHeight),
          Text('test')
        ],
      ));
}
```

The _buildAppBar method returns a SliverAppBar.

I need to use a Padding widget instead of the text, but I think that it will be like the same, that's the same issue.

Comment: SliverToBoxAdapter

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Once you are working with slivers, you need to use a sliver child wrapping your other non-sliver widgets. Since you want to use `Padding`, you can actually take advantage of the `SliverPadding` widget, which accepts your `Text` as its child.

So, instead of having `Text('test')` as you have, replace it by `SliverPadding(child: Text('test))` instead.

There are a few sliver widgets that you may want to be aware of. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493372/is-there-any-definite-list-of-sliver-widgets) at Collin Jackson's accepted answer and also at [Slivers, Demystified](https://medium.com/flutter-io/slivers-demystified-6ff68ab0296f) article for better understanding.

Comment: There is no such field `child` in `SliverPadding`. It can only be used to wrap another sliver. Use `SliverToBoxAdapter` instead.

Answer (score 32):

I found a better way to use non-slivers inside a CustomScrollView, use SliverToBoxAdapter widget. Give your non-sliver widget as child of SliverToBoxAdapter widget and your work done.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            Positioned(
              child: Container(color: Colors.yellow),
              top: 50,
              left: 50,
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

[image: this is the output of the above code]

Comment: Easy and quick solution, thanks heaps!

Answer (score 5):

The best answer is not correct, it causes assertion `padding == null`.
@blaneyneil wrote the right solution: use to SliverToBoxAdapter.